# Plotting a 3D density map with colors interpolated between datapoints for large amount of data

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, interpolation, wolfram-mathematica

I have some data to be plotted (~100k lines) in the form x,y,z,c, where x,y,z are coordinates, and c is a color. The coordinates range between [-0.5,0.5], and the color ranges between [-n,n], where n is changing, but typically is a small number (e.g. 0.0001). I want to color my datapoints red if negative and blue if positive, and the darkness of it should range from very dark (furthest from zero) to white (in the center)... imagine it as a charge distribution, where center is neutral.

My Gnuplot script for plotting it in 3D and coloring it works, and is the following:

```
set palette defined  ( -0.01 "dark-red", 0 "white", 0.01 "dark-blue" ) 
sp "filename" u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 ps 1 palette not
```

The code produces a nice density map and due to the color of my data is centered around zero, the points are also colored properly.

Instead of having points, I would like to have a colored interpolated density map, where the color (~continuously..) changes between the points. So instead of a dark dot surrounded by lighter dots and then white dots (barely visible as intended), I would like to see a blob of color with changing darkness/intensity from the center.

I cannot really find a solution to it yet. (I accept any freely available software solutions, e.g. gnuplot, but I have also Mathematica)

Comment: Not sure if the following is maybe helpful...  https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/voxel.html

Comment: @theozh Good question, if that script be changed into something for me? It says "step through volume using the density values to color a surface", thus it uses the density of points as a color, high density is a certain color, and low density is a different color gradually. It uses most likely spherical coordinates, where the radius is a color. But reading Voxel's description, it is actually suitable for me! Thank you! Any idea about how fast is it for around 100k data points?

Comment: Actually, I haven't used it yet. So I don't know how it works. Take the file `voxel.dem` and `gen-random.inc` from the gnuplot/demo directory and set `nsamp = 100000`.

Comment: I quickly tried... generation of 100'000 points takes about 10 seconds on my old PC. Plotting is less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @theozh : post your tests(code?) and I'll upvote them. Interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mathematica one can even achieve better:

data = Import["your_file_path.txt", "Table"];

(* Extract columns x, y, z, and c *)
extractedData = data[[All, {2, 3, 4, 6}]];

(* Filter data based on the condition c > -0.0001 *)
filteredData = Select[extractedData, #[[4]] > -0.0001 &];

(* Plot the filtered data with ListDensityPlot3D *)
plot = ListDensityPlot3D[filteredData, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic];

(* Export the plot to a PNG file *)
Export["output_plot.png", plot]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will fully answer your question. I guess you need to play with the voxel feature. The example is boiled down from the [example on the gnuplot homepage](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/voxel.html) or the files `voxel.dem`, `gen-random.inc` and `stat.inc` from your local gnuplot/demo directory. I hope you can somehow use it for your case.

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4.0)

```
### plot density of points
reset session

t0 = time(0.0)
print("Please wait...")
# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 100000
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))):(rand(0)*0.005-0.001) w table
unset table
t1 = time(0.0)
print sprintf("Generating data  %.3f sec",t1-t0)

set xyplane relative 0
set view equal xyz
set palette defined  ( -0.01 "dark-red", 0 "white", 0.01 "dark-blue" ) 
set key noautotitle
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set xrange[-5:5]
set yrange[-5:5]
set zrange[-5:5]

# define 100 x 100 x 100 voxel grid
set vgrid $vdensity size 100
vclear $vdensity

# fill a spherical region around each point in $Data
vfill $Data using 1:2:3:(0.33):(1.0)

splot '++' using 1:(0):2:(voxel($1,0,$2)) with pm3d, \
      '++' using 1:2:(0):(voxel($1,$2,0)) with pm3d, \
      '++' using (0):1:2:(voxel(0,$1,$2)) with pm3d
t2 = time(0.0)
print sprintf("Plotting data    %.3f sec",t2-t1)
print sprintf("Total time       %.3f sec",t2-t0)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (on my 8 year old laptop)

```
Please wait...
Generating data  11.066 sec
vfill from $Data :
        radius 0.33 gives a brick of 7 voxels on x, 7 voxels on y, 7 voxels on z
        number of points input:      100000
        number of voxels modified: 14392591
Plotting data    42.266 sec
Total time       53.332 sec
```

[image]

Comment: So, in general, it is very nice what you are showing, however, it's not near the "quality" I want to produce, see the example: https://www.gauss-centre.eu/results/elementaryparticlephysics/study-of-electromagnetic-corrections-to-qcd
But i managed to make something like that with a Python package called "myavi" Still i need a room for improvement.

Comment: @Kregnach now, when you illustrate with an example what you are actually looking for, I probably wouldn't have posted this answer. No idea how they've done this and how the input data would look like. However, these are "solid" objects with an overlay of something which reminds me to vectors. Anyway, I hope you found your software tool to display your data. Maybe you can post your current graph as work-in-progress to give an impression about your data.

Comment: I added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I will present here an example code that produces something I want to see (it is not my personal resolution of the problem). Still not perfect, but I think this could be the way to it. I appreciate any further comments/solutions that can improve it.

Using datafile with a sample data:

```
1   -0.491412   -0.483779   -0.483779   4   0.00121829
2   -0.483779   -0.491412   -0.391221   7   0.000570934
3   -0.483779   -0.391221   -0.491412   7   0.00106746
4   -0.483779   -0.391221   -0.391221   4   0.000223109
5   -0.391221   -0.483779   -0.483779   7   0.000710743
6   -0.391221   -0.483779   -0.383588   4   -7.20294e-06
7   -0.391221   -0.383588   -0.483779   4   0.000269441
8   -0.383588   -0.391221   -0.391221   7   4.84198e-06
9   -0.451336   -0.423664   -0.423664   4   0.000522623
10  -0.423664   -0.451336   -0.451336   7   0.00239021
```

If someone needs the full data to play with it, just let me know, but I guess one can also just produce 4D spherical data for this purpose.

Of course, my data is much much longer (~100k datapoints), here first column is just an index from 1 --> N, then x,y,z,t, coordinates, then color (value of the charge). The code takes an argument of the filename and t, and plots sections for all "t" , so for all 3-dim hypersurfaces. And from that, I can make a "video" by gluing the pictures and presenting them after each other.

```
from sys import argv
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.api import tvtk

if len(argv)<3:
print(f"usage: python {argv[0]} <filename> <t_select>") 
exit(0)

data=np.loadtxt(argv[1])
data[:,4]-=4 # shift since code starts from 1 not 0

# center max topcharge dens
idx_max = np.argmax(data[:,5])
xyz_new_center=data[idx_max,1:4]
xyz_min=np.min(data[:,1:4],axis=0)
xyz_max=np.max(data[:,1:4],axis=0)
#xyz_shift=xyz_max-0.5*(xyz_max+xyz_min)
xyz_sizes=(xyz_max-xyz_min)
xyz_new_min=xyz_new_center-xyz_sizes/2.
xyz_new_max=xyz_new_center+xyz_sizes/2.

print("center:",xyz_new_center)
print("min coords:",xyz_min)
print("max coords:",xyz_max)

# set x in range [a,b]:
# x' = (x-0.5*(b+a)+b-a)%(b-a)+0.5*(b+a)

for i in range(3):
    data[:,1+i]=(data[:,1+i]-xyz_new_min[i]+xyz_sizes[i])%(xyz_sizes[i])+xyz_new_min[i] #+xyz_new_center[i]

def plot_contour3d_spatial_slice(data,t_select):
#    dat=data[np.abs(data[:,4]-t_select)<1e-8]
dat=data[np.abs(data[:,4]-t_select)<1e-8]
#    x, y, z = dat[:,1], dat[:,2], dat[:,3]
topcharge_density = dat[:,5]

points = dat[:,1:4] # x,y,z
ug = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid(points=points)
ug.point_data.scalars = topcharge_density
ug.point_data.scalars.name = "topcharge density"
ds = mlab.pipeline.add_dataset(ug)
delaunay = mlab.pipeline.delaunay3d(ds)
iso = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(delaunay)
iso.actor.property.opacity = 0.15
iso.contour.number_of_contours = 20

mlab.colorbar()

t_select=int(argv[2])
plot_contour3d_spatial_slice(data,t_select)

mlab.show()
```

In my current configuration, I have only one blob that I want to visualize, and the above code does that, relative nicely.

[image: Topological charge density]